# Точный сон потока с помощью стандартной библиотеки

Tags: c++

Стандартная библиотека. C++ 11.
Есть такой способ усыпить поток `std::this_thread::sleep_until`
Есть задача: обеспечить сон с  точностью до микросекунды.
Путем экспериментов выяснилось, что сам `sleep` дает погрешность ~56 микросекунд.
Таким образом получить сон с точностью до микросекунды с помощью `sleep-а` - проблема.
Есть ли какие то другие способы выполнить задачу?

Comment: О каких _гарантиях_ может идти речь, если у вас не real-time OS?

Comment: возможно, если станет понятно, зачем такой точный сон, то и решение альтернативное найдется.

Comment: `~56 микросекунд` Это вам еще повезло что процессор не загружен. Любой `sleep` потока означает `разбуди меня НЕ раньше чем`

Comment: @KoVadim  а собственно какая разница?  
Нужно решение. Решение с `while` не подходит - проц занимается, а это недопустимо

Comment: Попробуйте запустить в фоне что-нибудь тяжёлое (например, 20 экземпляров упаковки каталога Windows в разные файлы), и посмотрите на ваши паузы снова.

Comment: @VladD Это все понятно.  
Давайте отталкиваться от условия - другой нагрузки нет.

Comment: @КонстантинФомин на самом деле есть. Возможно, вы решаете задачу, которая имеет решение. Но Вы решили ее решать как задачу молотка.

Comment: @KoVadim ну хорошо. Задача - взвести сигнал дискретного выхода и удерживать его в таком состоянии какое то конкретное время. С погрешностью +/- 10%

Comment: так как не известно, куда именно выводится сигнал, то если это аудиокарта, то можно просто записать "правильный звук". А  можно сделать  на ардуинке свое маленькое устройство, которому и передавать правильные данные. А оно уже очень точно все удержит.

Comment: @KoVadim речь идет о платах дискретного ввода/вывода. Внешние (по отношению к ней) устройства не рассматриваются

Comment: тогда Вам нужно рассмотреть необходимость писать драйвер. Там получится сделать задержку.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70614/discussion-between---and-kovadim).

Comment: @KoVadim т.е. решений без стороннего железа нет?

Comment: можно поставить RealTime OS (QNX к примеру), там будут гаратнии на sleep.

Comment: QNX стоит немалых денег. Есть решения на базе Linux?

Comment: Возможно, эти платы уже имеют необходимый Вам функционал

Comment: @КонстантинФомин: Linux тоже не RTOS.

Comment: @VladD ну вроде как бывают и такие.